# URL field in Webforms

Tags: webforms

I see only e-mail and textfield, but no URL.

How can I add to my form URL field with the validation rules for URL? e.g.

```
http://somesite.com
```

or

```
somesite.com
```

or

```
www.somesite.com
```

?

Answer (score 2):

Well if you have tons of time you could implement a component type... but because that is unlikely you should just add a validation hook and a textfield to the webform. You could do a `valid_url($form_state['values'][[your_field_name']);` in your validation hook.

Someone asked this question on d.o previously [here](http://drupal.org/node/270477). You can find all sorts of examples on "things you may need to do special with a webform" [here](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/webform).

Another possible solution would be to install the [Webform Validation](http://drupal.org/project/webform_validation) module, add a regex validation to your field, and steal a known usable url validation regex like [drupal has](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/valid_url/7).

Comment: Any idea why this is not one of the default options (textfield, e-mail, date...) in the list of Webform option for fields? I mean you need to add URl in a form a lot of times. The question like e.g. "What is your website URL?" seems to be in the forms imho often. Or?

Comment: Because someone hasn't implemented a webform link component, or you and myself cannot find one. See here http://drupal.org/node/1660144

Comment: Anyway thanks, I will try webform validation and let you know if it works.

Answer (score 2):

There is a module called [webform_link](https://drupal.org/project/webform_link) that could also help you.

> This module verifies that a valid URL is entered and displays the
>   result as a link.